# Can we trim the contents of the comments textarea when editing as is done when the comment is displayed?

Tags: bug, edits, comments

Say you had this comment:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fierent ancillae vivendum at mei. Has harum fabulas te, ad malis doctus usu, eum alia instructior te. Ut-------------mazim ceteros consectetuer sea. At eam vidit sanctus.

(`-` is used to indicate whitespaces)

It would be rendered as:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fierent ancillae vivendum at mei. Has harum fabulas te, ad malis doctus usu, eum alia instructior te. Ut mazim ceteros consectetuer sea. At eam vidit sanctus.

(no spaces)

However, when you click *Edit*, in the textarea you'd see the untrimmed comment (with the whitespaces).

<sup>This can be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) but I'm leaning towards [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because the displayed comments show the trimmed output.</sup>

Comment: Mmmmh. Consecutive spaces are not rendered because HTML is like that, consecutive spaces      get ignored. If anything, this is a FR and not a bug, since it's working s expected. It saves what you write, and it displays what is saved. Trimming extra consecutive spaces in comment would be a new feature, and very low value feature IMO.

Comment: (The above comment has consecutive spaces and these are rendered properly, it's the browser the one collapsing the consecutive spaces into a single white-space, as per the spec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No.

This is not a bug. As [yivi already pointed out in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382751/can-we-trim-the-contents-of-the-comments-textarea-when-editing-as-is-done-when-t#comment687018_382751), HTML ignores consecutive whitespace, collapsing it all into a single space.

Furthermore, there is no feature to be implemented here. It's normal, expected behavior that the rendered output be different from the raw input. This happens in the full Markdown text editor, too.

If I return to "edit" mode, I expect to see *exactly* what I entered—not some rendered/sanitized version of it.

Line breaks are also ignored in comments, but you can type line breaks into the editor. When you return to "edit" mode, you still see the line breaks.